# Undefined method `map' when creating new JSON record when using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the error:

```
undefined method `map' for #<String:0x000000011fe89ef8> Did you mean? tap
```

When trying to create a new record.

**Example URL from my CSV**

```
//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0613/5349/2701/products/18_720x.jpg?v=1648711965
```

**My schema:**

```
t.json "images"
```

**Importer view**

```
  <div class="importer">
    <h2>Importar productos a catálogo</h2>
    <%= form_tag importador_path, multipart: true do %>
      <%= file_field_tag :images, multiple: true %>
      <%= submit_tag "Importar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= @importerrors %>
  </div>
```

**Product.rb**

```
  def self.my_import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      images = "https://" + row['images']
      uploader = ImagesUploader.new
      uploader.download! images
      output = uploader.store!(images)
      finalimage = uploader.url[0]

      @product = Product.create(
        name: row['name'],
        active: row['active'],
        costprice: row['costprice'],
        category_id: row['category_id'],
        price: row['price'],
        provider: row['provider'],
        tipo: row['tipo'],
        description: row['description'],
        images: finalimage
      )

      puts @product.images

      @product.save
      if @product.save
        puts "Saved!"
      else
        puts @product.errors.full_messages
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: how are you attaching images to products? Are you using Rails ActiveStorage?

Comment: I'm using Carrierwave!

Comment: I'm inferring that you're uploading multiple images per product, so images should be an array, `@product = Product.new(.... , images: ["square-1.jpg"], ...)`

Comment: can you please add console params to questions?

Comment: @LesNightingill still getting the error.... I updated the code above

Comment: I can't tell from your code... is the value of the images key used in `Product.create` a string or an array?

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple uploads Carrierwave expects an array. This is determined by the name you pass to `mount_uploaders`:

> Make sure that you mount the uploader with write (mount_uploaders) with s not (mount_uploader) in order to avoid errors when uploading multiple files
>
> Make sure your file input fields are set up as multiple file fields. For example in Rails you'll want to do something like this:
> `<%= form.file_field :avatars, multiple: true %>`
>
> Also, make sure your upload controller permits the multiple file upload attribute, pointing to an empty array in a hash. For example:
> `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, {avatars: []})`
>
> See: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads

```ruby
@product = Product.create(
  # ActiveModel does not really care if you mix string and symbol keys
  row.slice(
    'name', 'active', 'costprice', 'category_id', 
    'price', 'provider', 'tipo', 'description'
  ).merge(
    images: ["square-1.jpg"]
  )
end
```

Comment: Thanks max, I'm still getting the error, I've updated my code so you can see full action

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.my_import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      images = "https://" + row['images']
      uploader = ImagesUploader.new
      uploader.download! images
      output = uploader.store!(images)

      @product = Product.new(
        name: row['name'],
        active: row['active'],
        costprice: row['costprice'],
        category_id: row['category_id'],
        price: row['price'],
        provider: row['provider'],
        tipo: row['tipo'],
        description: row['description'],
        images: [uploader]
      )

      puts @product.images

      @product.save
      if @product.save
        puts "Saved!"
      else
        puts @product.errors.full_messages
      end
    end
  end
```